# Remove element from a set only if element is in it

Tags: clojure

A list of players is defined as a set:

```
(def players (atom #{}))
```

Function that removes player should return different HTTP codes based on whether element was in the set or not:

```
(defn remove-player [player-name]
  (if (contains? @players player-name)
    (do (swap! players disj player-name)
        (status (response "") 200))
    (status (response "") 404)))
```

The problem with this code is that it might return multiple `200` to concurrent requests, even if only one request actually removed the element.

I guess I need to execute both `contains?` and `disj` atomically. Do I need to do explicit locking or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can move if condition it ```swap!``` function making both ```contains?``` and ```disj``` calls atomic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `swap!` itself is atomic operation, so inside the swap's calculating function you can be sure that the first parameter (atom's current value) is consistent. Personally i would make a helper function for that like this:

```
(defn remove-existent [value set-a]
  (let [existed (atom false)]
    (swap! set-a
           #(if (contains? % value)
              (do (reset! existed true)
                  (disj % value))
              (do (reset! existed false) 
                  %))
    @existed))
```

as you can see, lambda expression contains both existency check and removal.

```
user> (def players (atom #{:user1 :user2}))
#'user/players

user> (remove-existent :user100 players)
false

user> (remove-existent :user1 players)
true

user> @players
#{:user2}
```

**update**

Inspired by @clojuremostly's excellent metadata approach, you can make it much better:

```
(defn remove-existent [value set-a]
  (-> (swap! set-a #(with-meta (disj % value)
                      {:existed (contains? % value)}))
      meta
      :existed))
```

Comment: thanks, I couldn't figure out how to return both new set and a flag, you solved it nicely using atom.

Comment: updated my code to reset atom to false, if the value wasnt existing.

Comment: do we actually need to reset it? `existed` is local, isn't it?

Comment: yes we do have to. Because the swap! can be restarted multiple times, depending on the other thread' changes to `players`. So if we have player1 and another thread removes it, the swap! would be restarted, and `existed` needs to be refreshed.

Comment: We attach the metadata to the updated set and put it into the atom, right? To read the `existed` metadata we would need that new set object, won't we?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118044/discussion-between-damluar-and-leetwinski).

Comment: yes, it puts meta into the atom, as a side effect. But we don't read it from there, we read it from the return value of `swap!` function, and it is guaranteed to correspond the update result. But it is important that all metadata attached to atom's value would be overwritten. So if you use meta extensively, better fall back to my first variant with atom

Answer (score 2):

You can just add some more logic to your swapping function:

```
(for [el-rem [:valid-el :not-there]]
  (let [a (atom #{:valid-el :another-one})
        disj-res
        (swap! a
               (fn [a]
                 (with-meta (disj a el-rem)
                            {:before-count (count a)})))]
    [disj-res
     "removed:"
     el-rem
     (not (== (:before-count (meta disj-res))
              (count disj-res)))]))
```

You then compare the count of the return value `disj-res` and the count in the meta data. If it differs, then `disj` did remove an element. If not, the element was not present.

Comment: do you mean I should save the current count before doing swap and then compare them? doesn't it have the same problem? the difference could be any value (+100, -50, ...)

Comment: Nope, even if the atom changes under you, the return value of `swap!` will still be the snapshot at the time when you `disj`. So it's completely safe and it should be 2x faster since you don't have to run `contains?` over it.